# Getting access to a spring bean from a webservice?

Tags: spring, cxf, javabeans

I have created a cxf webservice within my cxf.xml file I have the following tag.
 bean id="videoStatsTable" class="com.company.auth.dataobjects.VideoStatsTable"

From what I understand Spring should create this object for me. The problem is I'm not sure how to get access to it. It seems as if I need the servletContext but as I'm in not in a servlet im in a WS im not sure how to do this?

W

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring has a simplifed way of declaring web services (wiht cxf).

in your `applicationContext.xml` add `xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"` to your root tag (`<beans>`) and

```
http://cxf.apache.org/core
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
```

to your `schemaLocation`

Then add:

```
<!-- Loading CXF modules -->
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
```

And finally declare your WebService implementation:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="MyWebService" implementor="#MyWebServiceImpl"
    address="/myWebServiceAddress" />
```

where `#MyWebServiceImpl` is the ID of your bean. You can freely inject any other spring dependencies into that bean.

Then the web service will be accessible through `http://yourhost/cxfuri/myWebServiceAddress` (where cxfuri is the mapping of your CXF Servlet)